# Breeze builds an invalid $filter

Tags: breeze

I have an entity called Workorders and one called WorkordersView - both point to the same table in the database.

Both have a field called "customerId" that is of type int.

When I query my view and set its where clause:

```
.where("customerId", "eq", "73")
```

it works file and produces this $filter:

[image]

but when I change the exact EntityQuery to point to the table entity, it creates it like this:

[image]

Which causes EF to throw errors because of the invalid datatype.

My first stop was to look at the metadata coming back to see if BreezeClient thought it was a string, but both the table and view version are both the data datatype of EdmInt32.

The view entity version:

[image]

and the table entity version:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see something like this, it is usually a good bet that you are NOT getting good metadata for the EntityType in question to the client. When you construct a query you are usually using a 'resourceName' to specify the endpoint of the query, breeze internally converts this to an EntityType via an EntityType/ResourceName map ( discussed in the documentation).  It is likely that this lookup is failing.  This is not necessarily a bug to breeze, because breeze also supports endpoints for which no metadata exists, but in these cases breeze needs additional information.

You can check this by going to the query after execution and using the EntityQuery.fromEntityType property (see http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#property_fromEntityType).  My guess is that this is returning an anonymous EntityType instead of the "WorkOrder" type that you are expecting. If so, then what is happening is that when breeze does not find an EntityType for the query in question, it has to guess as to the datatype of the filter clause.

To remedy this, either fix the problem that it causing you to get incorrect metadata ( usually the wrong resource name) or use the 'EntityQuery.toType' method to force the query to use a specified EntityType.  Both of these are discussed in the links below.

http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-result-debugging

A discussion of the resource name/entityType name mapping issue that you may be running into.

http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-from

Comment: Thanks Jay - I'll dig into this later today and see what I can find.  What's interesting is that the other tables in the DB seem to be working just fine it appears.